# npm build how to change package.json - homepage value by variable or script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-deployment, package.json, npm-build

I created my app using `create-react-app`, and I use `npm run build` to build the production package.

I need to put the app on different clients' sites, each client put the app on a different sub-folder.

e.g.
client A: `https://clientA.com/myApp`
client B: `https://clientB.com/UAT/myApp`
client C: `https://clientC.com/webApps/myApp`

everytime when I build the package, for different sub-folders, I need to modify the `homepage` value in `package.json`, build the package and repeat this steps mulltiple times.

My manual steps like:

1. modify `"homepage": "myApp"` > `npm run build` > save the build folder for deployment
2. modify `"homepage": "/UAT/myApp"` > `npm run build` > save the build folder for deployment
3. modify `"homepage": "/webApps/myApp"` > `npm run build` > save the build folder for deployment
4. keep repeatly doing the above.....

how can I improve this situation? how can I do build once to fit all different paths?
such as, can I use a variable in `homepage` value and set it up in environment variable?

or, can I write a script to do some? I hope to simpify this compile steps, ideally to execute the build or a building script once.

Thanks for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply build it once, and then use `vim` or any text editor to do the following operation on `index.html`: Replace `="/` with `="/myApp/` and `="/UAT/myApp/` and `=/webApps/myApp/` in the three folders respectively.
You can also use the `sed` utility to do that. Or maybe even automate it using a `bash` script.

It does work perfectly with Hash router

Comment: Thank you! this is the method most suitable for my situation! I have tried and this works for my deployment perfectly! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can just set `homepage` to `.` if you're using CRA 9.0 or newer:

> If you are not using the HTML5 pushState history API or not using client-side routing at all, it is unnecessary to specify the URL from which your app will be served. Instead, you can put this in your package.json:
>
> ```
>    "homepage": ".",
> ```
>
> This will make sure that all the asset paths are relative to index.html. You will then be able to move your app from http://mywebsite.com to http://mywebsite.com/relativepath or even http://mywebsite.com/relative/path without having to rebuild it.

– [the documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths)

Comment: is `react-router-dom` a kind of client-side routing? my app used `Switch`, `Route`, and `useHistory` (for push, go to a new route). That's why I need to set up the homepage value for build I think.

Comment: Are you using `BrowserRouter` or `HashRouter`?

Comment: yes I am using HashRouter. My project is a Single Page App. So I think client-side routing is necessary for my app. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I just tested it (on a gitlab page) and it is OK!
On top of that I use the line <base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/"> as the first header in public/index.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable when making build. The build command looks like:

```sh
PUBLIC_URL=https://clientA.com/myApp npm run build
```

You can create npm scripts to simplify it like:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build-clientA": "PUBLIC_URL=https://clientA.com/myApp react-scripts build",
    "build-clientB": "PUBLIC_URL=https://clientB.com/UAT/myApp react-scripts build",
  }
  ...
}
```

If you want to do one command to build for all of clients, simple bash script to build and move `build` folder should work fine, it looks like:

```sh
PUBLIC_URL=https://clientA.com/myApp react-scripts build && mv build clientA
PUBLIC_URL=https://clientB.com/UAT/myApp react-scripts build && mv build clientB
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set `homepage` like this :

```
"homepage": "/"
```

and build project once and handle this server side and read all routes from `index.html`

Comment: I just tested it (on a gitlab page) and it is not sufficient.